# EC2 php - Fail to echo variable

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just registered EC2 and copy over my project to the EC2 server, and then I notice one weird thing: some of the variable can not be printed

It is how it happened

```
<?php
$username = "John";
?>

<p>Name: <?=$username?>.</p>
```

The result is doesn't output username

```
Name: .
```

This method doesn't work in EC2, is there any configuration setting I need to change to make it work?

Comment: What php version are you running on EC2?

Comment: short tags .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: Yes, it is php version issue. I upgrade it to php 5.4 and it works now

Comment: or you could just stop using short tags

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion above, this is php version issue. only php 5.4 or higher version support short tags. it works after upgrading php version to 5.4.33

THanks

Comment: still should not use short tags regardless of version

Comment: @Dagon The short echo tags `<?=` are generally excepted and enabled by default. However, any short open tag is discouraged.